# Toolbar for matplotlib plot in wxpython is not working

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have managed to get the toolbar to show, however non of the buttons on the tool bar are responsive. I heard that the tool bar only works using a boxsizer and so tried to integrate that into the code by placing a boxsizer within a gridbag sizer. This did not work. I have updated both matplotlib and wxpython to the newest versions as of today. Please look at my code as I think I might be missing something obvious.

```
class Example(wx.Frame):  
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,size=(628, 708))

    self.InitUI()
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()     

def InitUI(self):
    self.locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)

    font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
    font.SetPointSize(9)                    
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(8, 4)

    title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="WORK FUNCTION CALCULATOR", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(title, pos=(0, 1),span = (1,5), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, border=20)

    tp = wx.StaticText(panel, label="File To Process", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(tp, pos=(1, 0),span = (1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)

    od1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Work Function", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(od1, pos=(1, 4),span = (1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)     

    od2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Ratio of Counts", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(od2, pos=(2, 0),span = (1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)

    od3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Applied Bias", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(od3, pos=(3, 0),span = (1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=50)

    od4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Method of Calculation", style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )
    sizer.Add(od4, pos=(1, 2),span = (1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)

    self.listbox1 = wx.ListBox(panel,-1,size=(110, 22))
    self.listbox1.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)
    dt = FileDrop(self.listbox1)
    self.listbox1.SetDropTarget(dt)
    sizer.Add(self.listbox1, pos=(1, 1),  flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=10)

    self.listbox2 = wx.ListBox(panel,-1,size=(150, 25))
    sizer.Add(self.listbox2, pos=(2, 4),flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=10)

    self.ratioTC = wx.TextCtrl(panel,wx.TE_PASSWORD)
    sizer.Add(self.ratioTC, pos = (2,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=10)

    self.biasTC = wx.TextCtrl(panel,wx.TE_PASSWORD)
    sizer.Add(self.biasTC, pos = (3,1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.BOTTOM, border=10)

    buttonProcess = wx.Button(panel, label="Process -->")
    buttonProcess.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnProcess)
    sizer.Add(buttonProcess, pos=(2, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)



    methods = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    self.cb = wx.ComboBox(panel, pos=(50, 30), choices=methods,size = (100,20), style=wx.CB_READONLY)
    sizer.Add(self.cb, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.LEFT, border=10)


    self.figure = Figure()
    self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    vbox.Add(self.canvas,1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border=5)

    self.chart_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
    tw,th = self.chart_toolbar.GetSizeTuple()
    fw,fh = self.canvas.GetSizeTuple()
    self.chart_toolbar.SetSize(wx.Size(fw, th))
    self.chart_toolbar.Realize()
    vbox.Add(self.chart_toolbar,0,flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)

    sizer.Add(vbox, pos=(4,0), span=(4,5),flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE|wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)                  

    panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
    self.chart_toolbar.update()
    self.canvas.Update()
    self.canvas.Refresh()
    self.Update()
```

All other functions mentioned in this block of code do not affect the toolbar.

Comment: did you bind any function to the toolbar button?.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried adding `sizer` to `vbox` rather than the other way around

Comment: I have tried adding vbox to sizer not the other way round

Comment: The toolbar is not a button. I have not seen any examples of implementing a toolbar that involves binding a function to it

Comment: @Aaron, the purpose of the toolbar is to but some tools on it - usually buttons, like New, Open - and then react to clicks on those tools/buttons. Toolbar by itself is pretty useless

Comment: Maybe look at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html) and check if there is a difference, or use that example, incoorporate your code and compare it to your case.

Comment: I have looked at the example and tried incorporating into my code. The toolbar is still not responding. The difference between the example and my code is that in the example it calls a function to create the toolbar whereas mine just creates the toolbar without the use of a function. The code in the function and the code that creates the toolbar in my program are pretty much identical other than the size of the toolbar

Comment: In reply to Rolf, i hyave tried adding the sizers the other way round to no avail. In reply to Igor, the  NavigationToolbar2Wx creates the matplotlib toolbar already populated with buttons.